# Java Sockets, Receiving Empty File

Tags: java, file, sockets, transfer

I am creating an application to Send a File from a Client and Receive it with a Server via Socket.

When I test the Application in my PC (Client-Server on same PC) everything runs Ok, but When I test the application on different PCs I've got the following errors.

1. First Attempt: Nothing happen, no errors, no file sent.
2. Second Attempt: Java throws an error of Ip already in use, but I receive the file on my Server PC but it has no data on it.

Here is the code for Client:

```
    public class FileSender {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
FileSender nioClient = new FileSender();
SocketChannel socketChannel = nioClient.createChannel();
try {
    nioClient.sendFile(socketChannel);
} catch (FileNotFoundException | InterruptedException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
//SocketChannel socketChannel = nioClient.createc
    }
public SocketChannel createChannel(){

    SocketChannel socketChannel = null;

    try {
        socketChannel = SocketChannel.open();
        SocketAddress socketAddress = new InetSocketAddress("xx.xxx.xxx.x", 10002);
        socketChannel.connect(socketAddress);
        System.out.println("Connected..Now Sending the File");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
return socketChannel;   
}

public void sendFile(SocketChannel socketChannel) throws FileNotFoundException, InterruptedException{

    RandomAccessFile afile = null;

    try {
        File file = new File("/home/dionisio/Imágenes/ImagenesOriginalesPrueba/flowers.jpg");
        afile = new RandomAccessFile(file, "r");
        FileChannel inChannel = afile.getChannel();
        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(8192);
        while (inChannel.read(buffer) != -1) {
            buffer.flip();
            socketChannel.write(buffer);
            buffer.clear();     
        }
        socketChannel.close();
        afile.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

Server Code

```
public class FileReceiver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
FileReceiver nioServer = new FileReceiver();
SocketChannel socketChannel = nioServer.createServerSocketChannel();
nioServer.readFileFromSocket(socketChannel);
    }

    private SocketChannel createServerSocketChannel() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ServerSocketChannel serverSocketChannel = null;
        SocketChannel socketChannel = null;

        try {
            serverSocketChannel = ServerSocketChannel.open();
            serverSocketChannel.socket().bind(new InetSocketAddress(10002));
            socketChannel = serverSocketChannel.accept();
            System.out.println("Connection Stablished..."+socketChannel.getRemoteAddress());

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return socketChannel;
    }


    private void readFileFromSocket(SocketChannel socketChannel) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    RandomAccessFile afile = null;

    try {
        afile = new RandomAccessFile("/home/dionisio/Imágenes/imagenesCopiaPrueba/flowersCopia.jpg","rw");
        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(8192);
        FileChannel fileChannel = afile.getChannel();
        while (socketChannel.read(buffer)>0) {
            buffer.flip();
            fileChannel.write(buffer);
            buffer.clear();
        }
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        fileChannel.close();
        System.out.println("End of file reached...Closing Channel");
        socketChannel.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your read loops aren't correct. They should be of the form:

```
while (in.read(buffer) > 0 || buffer.position() > 0)
{
    buffer.flip();
    out.write(buffer);
    buffer.compact();
}
```

Otherwise you can lose data.

NB

- Java does not throw an error 'IP already in use'. Be accurate.
- You don't need the sleep. Don't add sleeps to networking code. It doesn't solve anything.

Comment: Hi EJP thank's for that tip, I'm going to try that to see what happens.

But prior testing your code, is there a reason to make my code works (obviously without your new code yet) in my localhost but not in different PCs?

Comment: I already tried your code but I still having the same problem :( 

Ah if you see my code you can see that I have a println that reads something like "connection established", that output is not showed in different PCs but in localhost.

I don't know if the problems comes from the fact that I am running the Client in Linux and the Server in Windows, that should not be the problem because Java is cross platform.

Answer (score -1):

My folks thanks for your replies, now I know what was my error, I was putting the wrong Ip address on my client Application.

However EJP I will take your recommendation for a better byte check when writing on a Channel.

Comment: If you had the wrong IP address there is no way you could have received an empty file.